# Ubuntu dotnet core user secrets error

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core

Here is my error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: paths
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String[] paths)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.PathHelper.GetSecretsPathFromSecretsId(String userSecretsId)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.PathHelper.GetSecretsPath(IFileProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationExtensions.AddUserSecrets(IConfigurationBuilder configuration)
   at WebApplication.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in /root/hackerspulse/Startup.cs:line 29
```

Startup.cs line 29 is this:

```
    builder.AddUserSecrets();
```

More code from that file:

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);



            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
                // For more details on using the user secret store see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets();
            //}
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

It runs fine from command line, but when I try to run it from supervisor I get this error :( Please help.

Comment: I learned a work around: Not using user secrets and using appsettings.json file instead ... kind of bad work around but works

Comment: Do you have this error with a published app or you run from the project?

Comment: @MikhailZhuravlev Run from the project is fine, published app with supervisor command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/jademgr/jademgr.dll gets error

Answer (score -1):

Secret Manager is for development time only. Please **don't** use in production environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets

Comment: Just because it's on a development server, it doesn't necessarily mean that is production use, it could be a QA/Test Environment, I develop locally on a windows machine but I intend to host in a Linux environment due to the reduced cost of managing a Linux host vs a Windows host, which is what .NET Core is all about support cross platform. In a nutshell, my current Linux Server which is my Development server